# SYMPY: How to simplify sqrt ratio?

Tags: sympy

I would like to simplify sqrt ratios.
For example :

```
import sympy as sp
a,b=sp.symbols("a b", real=True)
myExpr=sp.sqrt(b/a)*sp.sqrt(a/b)
```

Why does not myExpr simplify to **1** ?

I tried many things that does not work :

```
myExpr.simplify()
...
myExpr.refine(sp.Q.positive(a)&sp.Q.positive(b)&sp.Q.real(a)&sp.Q.real(b))
```

How can I simplify such expressions ?

My expressions are much more complex than this simple case. It is a sum of product of terms. For example, one term of the sum is :

```
myExpr=sp.sqrt((2*a**2+1-2*a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1))/(a**2+1-a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1)))/sp.sqrt(a**2+1-a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1))*sp.sqrt((2*b**2+1-2*b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1))/(b**2+1-b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1)))/sp.sqrt(b**2+1-b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1))
```

And its simplification (done by hand) is

```
mySimplif=sp.sqrt((2*a**2+1-2*a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1)))/(a**2-a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1)+1)+sp.sqrt((2*b**2+1-2*b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1)))/(b**2-b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1)+1)
```

To be complete, I use this workaround (not very convenient):

```
c=sp.symbols("c",positive=True)
myExpr.subs(sp.sqrt(a**2+1-a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1)),c).subs(c,sp.sqrt(a**2+1-a*sp.sqrt(a**2+1))).subs(sp.sqrt(b**2+1-b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1)),c).subs(c,sp.sqrt(b**2+1-b*sp.sqrt(b**2+1)))
```

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need `a` and `b` to be positive rather than just real:

```
In [15]: a, b = symbols('a, b', positive=True)

In [16]: sqrt(b/a)*sqrt(a/b)
Out[16]: 1
```

Otherwise if they can be negative then you could have e.g. `a = -1` and `b = 1` in which case the simplification would not be valid:

```
In [21]: a = sympify(-1)

In [22]: b = sympify(1)

In [23]: sqrt(a/b)*sqrt(b/a)
Out[23]: -1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. This was a simple case. I edit my question with the full problem.It is also related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/66439698/7462275

Comment: Concerning your answer, I agree with you when b/a is negative. But  why `myExpr.refine(sp.Q.positive(a/b))` does not work ? I ask this question because in other cases, I used `refine` with assumptions to simplify complex expressions.

Comment: Looks like this case is not implemented in refine yet

Comment: So I use the workaround with substitute (see my question).

Comment: There is also `powsimp(..., force=True)`